# X keyboard layout occasionally resets itself

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have this in my .xinitrc:

```
setxkbmap -layout "jp,ru" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

(I'm in Japan, have a local keyboard, and occasionally use the Russian keyboard layout)

This works fine, most of the time:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     jp,ru
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

But occasionally, I'm no longer able to switch to Russian.  When I repeat the above command, I get:

```
misha@misha-lmd:~$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     jp
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

So something is changing the X keyboard layout.  What could it be, and how do I get rid of it?  It's annoying to have to do `setxkbmap -layout "jp,ru" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"` every time the Russian layout stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu intermittently checks if there are X settings and removes them to prevent conflicts with dbus's window manager configuration.

Instead of using X settings you should configure the keyboard using dbus.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I noticed Fcitx (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fcitx) was being run on the start. So I configured Fcitx for my layout and got it resolved.